# Integrity error when trying to save many-to-many field data

Tags: python, django

I have a Course model and a StudentData model. In order to enroll students to courses, I added a many-to-many field to the Course model. I can list the students with a checkbox, but problem is, when I press the Enroll button, to add those students to the course, I get the following error: http://dpaste.com/3E1XR4P

```
#views.py

if request.method == "POST":
        form = CourseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            redirect('classroom')
    else:
        form = CourseForm()

#forms.py

     class CourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Course
        fields = ('student', )
        widgets = {
            'student': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
        }

#models.py


class StudyProgramme(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey('Department', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    studies_type = models.IntegerField(choices=((0, "Bachelor Studies"),
                                                (1, "Master Studies"),
                                                (2, "Doctoral Studies"),
                                                (3, "Integrated Studies")), default=0)
    duration = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(99)])
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=140, unique=False, default=None, null=True, blank=True)

class Course(models.Model):
    study_programme = models.ForeignKey('StudyProgramme', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    ects = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(99)])
    description = models.TextField()
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(99)])
    semester = models.IntegerField(choices=((1, "1"),
                                            (2, "2"),
                                            ), default=None)
    teacher1 = models.ForeignKey('TeacherData', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None,
                                 verbose_name="Course Teacher", related_name='%(class)s_course_teacher')
    teacher2 = models.ForeignKey('TeacherData', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, null=True,
                                 verbose_name="Seminar Teacher", related_name='%(class)s_seminar_teacher')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    student = models.ManyToManyField('StudentData', default=None)
class StudentData(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    student_ID = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=14)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, blank=True)
    enrolled = models.BooleanField(default=False)

#enroll.html

 <form action="" id="form" method=POST>
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    {{ form.as_p }}
                                    <input type="submit" value="Enroll">
                                </form>
```

Thing is the if I add null=True to every field, makes no sense.

Comment: Your CourseForm only contains the student field, but your view is trying to create a whole new Course on save. You need to get the course you are want to enroll the students for, and pass it to the form to be updated. To be honest, a form is probably overkill for this.

Comment: What else I could use instead ? I also think its not that good using a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do here is just to pass the students to the template and create checkboxes there manually, then pass the values directly to the course.

```
def enroll_students(request, course_slug):
    course = Course.objects.get(slug=course_slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        course.student.add(*request.POST.getlist('student_ids'))
        return redirect('...')
    return render(request, 'enroll_students.html', {'students': StudentData.objects.all()})
```

...

```
<form action="." method="POST">
{% for student in students %}
    <label for="id_{{ student.id }}">{{ student.name }}</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="id_{{ student_id }}" value="{{ student.id }}" name="student_ids">

{% endfor %}
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: (*request.POST.getlist('student_ids') this line refers student_id or student_ID ? Because I have no 'student_ids'. The checkbox works and everything. The students even get paginated, and Im happy that is also working but if I check my Course model in admin, no students appear to be selected.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `name` attribute in the HTML input, updated.

Comment: if I could get one small update.. how can I do it that I can select more at a time and update those selected ? Instead of just one.

Comment: sorry but I had to modify it in this way: https://pastebin.com/u5qpvxdT in order to display things in page as I wanted. So the students iteration went outside the form. Is there a way to keep this behaviour but enable multiple selection ?